# conexión a 4D Database desde Django

Tags: python, django

conexión desde Django a 4dimension database, para solo lectura de datos y poder mostrarlos en un template, sin tener que usar modelos.

Comment: Por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: gracias davidddd

Comment: También por favor agrega [un ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic